Working on a Project Name : Deploying lms application using docker
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/lms-fenew" is already in use by container "22e160b0ca638f88bc8cc45dd5521f2ac67cc956769ada281d6ad68dd0ed2e1d". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
I am Trying Run the cmd in Gitbash is : docker container run -dt --name lms-fenew -p 80:80 yameen54/lms-fe
But i am getting Error : docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/lms-fenew" is already in use by container "22e160b0ca638f88bc8cc45dd5521f2ac67cc956769ada281d6ad68dd0ed2e1d". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

As the error says, you already have a container running with that name.  If you're sure you don't need it, you can docker stop lms-fenew && docker rm lms-fenew before docker running a new one.
